# Bootstrap multiselect preselected option not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I am using bootstrap multiselect and Select with preselected options Cheese is not working? Why?

this is my html

```
<div class="input-group">
                    <!-- input type="text" class="form-control turnusdays infofield" id="turnusdays1"-->
                    <!-- div class="info"></div -->
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <select class="multiselectDays turnusdays" multiple="multiple">
                            <option value="Pon">Pon</option>
                            <option value="Tor">Tor</option>
                            <option value="Sre">Sre</option>
                            <option value="Čet">Čet</option>
                            <option value="Pet" selected>Pet</option>
                            <option value="Sob">Sob</option>
                            <option value="Ned">Ned</option>
                            <option value="Vikend">Vikend</option>
                            <option value="Praznik">Praznik</option>
                        </select>

                    </span>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting ? If its MVC then use Listboxfor for multiselect.

**Updated**

! [image]

Code here is :

```
  <select multiple="multiple" style="width:500px;height:300px">
                <option value="Pon" selected>Pon</option>
                <option value="Tor">Tor</option>
                <option value="Sre">Sre</option>
                <option value="Čet">Čet</option>
                <option value="Pet" selected>Pet</option>
                <option value="Sob" selected>Sob</option>
                <option value="Ned">Ned</option>
                <option value="Vikend">Vikend</option>
                <option value="Praznik">Praznik</option>
            </select>
```

Remove the div and span class and try only the select option.

Comment: Value (Pet) is not selected on page load. I have a JSON with data and some values need to be preselected

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Its working fine for me. Also check whether other input controls working for you and also check with other latest browsers.

Comment: I solved it with $('.turnusMultiselectDays',r).val(days);, where days is an array of elements.